# Is "I am reading a book against the bed" correct?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

> I am reading a book against the bed.

Don't we use against as 'in contact with'?

Comment: Why did you choose the word **against** for this sentence? Was this a multiple choice question in a test?

Comment: @P.E.Dant No sir.Someone asked me this doubt

Comment: Do you mean that someone asked you if "I am reading a book against the bed" is a correct sentence?

Comment: @P.E.Dant yes sir

Comment: Well, that makes it easier to understand! In English, we say "in bed" (without the article "the") when a person uses the bed to sleep or to do anything. We might say "on the bed" or "in the bed" when we sit or recline using the bed. The dictionary (like [this one](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/against?s=t)) gives many meanings for **against,** but if you read them, you will see that most of them are about _opposition_ of some kind. Your sentence would properly be: _"I am reading a book **in** bed."_ (It is very polite to do so, but there is no need to address us here as _Sir_ or _Ma'am._)

Comment: Good luck to you, @KrishnaVamsiVedula ! Just one other thing: when you use punctuation, place a space after it: 1. _This is incorrect.Do not do this._  2. _This is correct. Do it this way._

Answer (score 3):

"Against" can indeed mean "in contact with",  but it reads oddly here, for a number of reasons.

First, I think it is relatively rare as an adverbial modifier (modifying a verb phrase) in this meaning: it is more common as an adjectival modifier ("the book against the bed") or as an argument of a verb like "put" or "place".

Secondly, semantically "against the bed" seems rather unclear. If you're talking about moving furniture, it makes sense ("We pushed the table against the bed") but I don't know quite what "read the book against the bed" would mean.

Answer (score 2):

That sentence implies some pretty strange behavior, though I have an exception to note below. You are correct that "against" can be used to mean "in contact with" but it is almost always used to connote forcefulness, with an implication of conflict or opposition. You press something *against* another thing.

I'm guessing that you want to say "I'm in bed, reading a book," or "I'm reading a book in bed."

The exception I wanted to note: there is one case where your sentence would make perfect sense, and that's if you're using the bed from some position other than on/in it. For example, if you're sitting on the floor and using the side or end of the bed as a prop to keep you upright, you might note your position as "against the bed."

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am in a sleeping position and reading a book.So, is it a wrong one?